# Intellij IDEA Community Edition - Breakpoints not working for methods with aspects weaved at compile time

Tags: java, intellij-idea, aspectj

I'm using Intellij IDEA Community Edition 13 and have some methods annotated with `@Something` which is an aspect weaved at compile time. When trying to debug the method annotated, for some reason I am not able to step into any breakpoint.

I just started working with aspects, so I may be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in IntelliJ IDEA 13: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117936. It was solved in version 13.0.1: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+13.0.1+Release+Notes. It should work after you update.

Regards,

Cata

Answer (score 0):

Did you try debug on another code ? Maybe you press RUN( SHIFT+F10) while need to press DEBUG(SHIFT+F9).

Comment: Debugging on other methods that are not annotated with an aspect works as it should.